# How to record other events in FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am using FlatList to render items. Each item is a separate card style component. Each item has `onPress` event handler which changes the component.

Here is my Flatlist.

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return <CardItem courseData={item} />
  }}
  ref={this.flatList}
  keyExtractor={
    (item) => { return item.content_address }
  }
  initialNumToRender={10}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
/>
```

Here is the CardItem Component

```
constructor{
    this.state = {change:false}
} 

_onPress = () => {
    this.setState({change: true})
}

render() {
    if (this.state.change) {
        return (//return changes)
    } else {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                ref="myRef"
                activeOpacity={0.5}
                onPress={this._onPress}>
                ... 
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

**Now what I want is to have only one card component changed at a time.**

So when a user touches on 1st card component, it should change. But when a user touches 2nd card component, 1st should change back to the previous state and 2nd should change.

I saw FlatList documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#methods) but not sure which methods can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you store your toggled item in parent state you can check and render accordingly. Also storing toggled value in child state will cause a bug where if the item moves enough off to the screen it will be unmounted and the internal state of the child component will be reset. This would cause undesired toggle in your list. Storing state in parent component will help to overcome this issue.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { toggledItem: null }
  }

  onPressItem = (itemId) => {
    this.setState({toggledItem: itemId})
  }

  render() {
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return <CardItem 
                  courseData={item} 
                  onPress={this.onPressItem} 
                  toggeled={item.id === this.state.toggledItem} 
                />
      }}
      ref={this.flatList}
      keyExtractor={
          (item) => { return item.content_address }
      }
      initialNumToRender={10}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
    />
  }
}
```

---

```
class CardItem extends Component {
  _onPress = () => {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.courseData.id)
  }
  render() {

      if (this.props.toggeled) {
          return (//return changes)
      } else {
          return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                  ref="myRef"
                  activeOpacity={0.5}
                  onPress={this._onPress}>
                  ... 
              </TouchableOpacity>
          )
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! it's working. Just a small edit into CardItem's props instead of `toggeled={item.id === this.state.toggledItem}` it will be `                 toggeled={item.content_address === this.state.toggledItem} `